# How do we calculate the rise in DC bus voltage during negative torque conditions on a PMSM Motor

Tags: pmsm, regenerative

I have two PMSM motors connected back to back with a coupled shaft.
Both the motors have independent motor drive inverters driving them.
One motor (Motor A) is operating in speed mode, meaning its job is to maintain a constant speed set by the user.
The other motor (Motor B) is operating in torque mode, meaning it can provide torque in both clockwise and anti-clockwise directions based on the torque setpoint set by the user.

If Motor B provides torque in the same direction of rotation as Motor A, Motor A starts acting like a generator (quadrant 2 or 4 in a general four quadrant torque speed curve of a motor), the connected DC bus capacitor bank voltage of Motor A starts to raise, and this excess energy is generally wasted on a brake resistor (regenerative braking).

I would like to know, is there any way to find out how much will be the rise in the DC bus voltage on the Motor A side, given that we know how much torque Motor B is providing and at what speed Motor A is rotating and the DC bus capacitance of Motor A?

Thanks!

Comment: It's got nothing to do with torque; it's all about the speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have experience with exactly the same type of setup as you mention.
The short answer is that the voltage rise will be very high and very swift, because those capacitors don't hold a lot of energy compared to what a PMSM motor consumes in a second. But for analysis sake, here's the math:

**Formula 1: Power (W) = Torque (N.m) x Speed (RPM) / 9.5488**

Example: your motors spin at 2000 RPM and you get -10Nm of torque regen. So your "braking" motor converts 10 * 2000 / 9.5488 = 2095W.

In reality, neither the motor nor the controller is 100% efficient, so if you allow 11% for losses, this is 1865 W being dumped to the DC bus.

**Formula 2: Current (A) = Power (W) / Voltage (V)**

Example: your DC bus is at 48V, so 1865/48 = 38.8A.
These 38.8 amps will flow into the DC bus trying to charge capacitors and raise the voltage.

**Formula 3: Voltage rise (dV) = Current (A) * Time (s) / Capacitance (F)**

Example: assuming bus capacitance of 10000µF (which is just 0.01F), for 1 millisecond you'll get a rise of 38.8 * 0.001 / 0.01 = 3.88V.

Yes, your DC bus will rise at nearly 4 volts per **millisecond**, assuming nothing else "eats" that excess energy.
If your electronics are intended to operate on 48V and will die if 65V are exceeded, this excess will be reached within 4 milliseconds.

**Edit**: on a second read, Formula 3 is slightly misleading: as your bus voltage gets up, the constant power being fed via Formula 2 will mean less current will be charging the caps. I.e. the voltage rise will not be linear, but will slow down a bit as the caps charge up. But this does not buy you much in terms of time, maybe it slows down the "electronics fried" moment from 4-5ms to 10ms tops. That's still not much.

A better way to model this is another formula: capacitor energy is Voltage (V) squared × Capacitance (F) / 2.
I.e. if the caps are rated for 65 volts and their capacitance is 10000µF (as before), their total energy when fully charged is 65²*0.01 / 2 = 21.125 joules.
When they are charged to 48 volts (your initial bus voltage as per my example), they hold 11.52 joules. About halfway charged as far as energy goes.
The point is the PMSM wants to put 1865 joules *per second* into your capacitor bank; either way, they'll fill up very quickly, in less than 10ms.

Comment: Thanks @anrieff, this was very help full. One follow up question, would the type of capacitor used have any effect on the voltage raise? Ex: A 10000uF film capacitor bank vs a 10000uF electrolytic capacitor bank?

Comment: The type of capacitor wouldn't matter in theory. In practice they have different ESR, but in the controllers they would want to use caps with low ESR, so it will be close to what the theory says.